# Bitvise SSH Keypair

Tags: ssh, bitvise

I'm using the Bitvise SSH Client's Tunneling program stnlc.exe and I'm trying to connect to my Bitvise SSH server by using a key pair. I created a Key pair in PuTTyGen, put the public key into the server successfully and I tell the client the private key file and passphrase and I get this error: "Warning: Importing keypair specified with -keypairFile parameter failed: KeypairImporter: unrecognized or invalid importformat. Make sure that this key is NOT only a public key, but a full private key or keypair"

It's the proper file name, proper format, and it's the match generated by PuTTyGen so I don't get it. Anyone know what the deal is>

Comment: what filename of the key are you importing ?   keyfile  or  keyfile.pub?

Comment: keyfile.ppk. I am trying to import the private key for pairing with the public one which is on the server.